# trouble with precompile on heroku cedar with jquery ui file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, precompile, cedar

I'm new to rails and heroku and was hoping someone could help me out with an issue I'm having. I have a cedar stack.  I added config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false to my application.rb file when I push it does 'Running: rake assets:precompile. I don't see any mention of my jquery-ui-1.8.18custom.css file specifically however. When I run heroku logs it complains this file is not precompiled. Am I missing something? When I try to precompile locally it just hangs, but its my understanding I shouldn't have to do it locally anyway and its best not to.

Any suggestions?

Here's the end of my push on heroku:

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   /usr/local/bin/ruby /tmp/build_3gao4dm3wwned/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin
/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
-----> Rails plugin injection
   Injecting rails_log_stdout
   Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types      -> (none)
   Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compiled slug size is 16.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v82
   http://MYAPPNAME.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

Here's my error log:

```
  2012-03-14T15:40:29+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

2012-03-14T15:40:29+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered homes/index.html.erb within layou
ts/application (0.4ms)
2012-03-14T15:40:29+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-03-14T15:40:29+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-03-14T15:40:29+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (jquery-ui-1.8
.18.custom isn't precompiled):
```

UPDATE:

I added config.assets.compile = true to production.rb and that seems to have solved the problem. Are there any issues with this?

As an alternative I had tried adding this to application.rb instead:  onfig.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css ) and then running rake precompile and I was still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be two things.  If you're trying to link direct to the asset from your views then you need to set it to pre-compile:

http://neilmiddleton.com/precompiling-non-default-assets-with-rails-3/

If, however, it's just in the tree and you're expecting it to be included with `application.css` then you need to ensure that it's either in the manifest directly, or in one of the included trees if there are any listed.

for instance (`application.css`):

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require "reset"
 *= require "base"
 *= require "jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom"
*/
```

Comment: I'm linking to it in my application.html.erb files like this: 
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom', 'application' %>. I tried editing my application.css file to look like this:  *= require_self
 *= require_tree
 *= require "jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom" .  and I got an error

Comment: Clarification, the error is still on heroku abut it not being precompiled, it still looks fine locally.

Comment: You shouldn't be linking directly to assets when using the assets pipeline.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: great resource, thanks! Should I still be including links to application.css and application.js in my application.html.erb file? I tried removing these locally and adding the correct .js and .css files to the application.css and application.js required lists but its not working.